# List with values present in all intervals

Tags: google-sheets

How to make a list with values that exists in all intervals?

Take columns with dates:

```
01/01/2020  01/01/2020  30/12/2019
02/01/2020  03/01/2020  01/01/2020
03/01/2020  04/01/2020  03/01/2020
```

The output should be:

```
01/01/2020
03/01/2020
```

Comment: are the intervals fixed at 3 columns or can be dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

If the dates in each column are unique, you can use this formula:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(FLATTEN(A1:C3),FLATTEN(COUNTIF(A1:C3,A1:C3)=3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Good spot - that may be what OP is assuming.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=FILTER(
 FILTER(A1:A, COUNTIF(B1:B, A1:A)), 
              COUNTIF(C1:C, 
 FILTER(A1:A, COUNTIF(B1:B, A1:A))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should be adaptable for different numbers of columns - tests for presence of three different combinations of column and date:

```
=ArrayFormula(filter(unique(flatten(A1:C3)),countif(unique(split(flatten(column(A1:C3)&"|"&A1:C3),"|")),unique(flatten(A1:C3)))=3))
```

[image]